# Handling Wordpress conditionals in OOP classes

Tags: php, wordpress, oop

With isolation testing and keeping classes testable in mind, how should I handle Wordpress conditional tags like `is_year()`, `is_day()`, `is_month()` etc inside an OOP class.

Take this example:

```
public function date()
{

    if (is_year()) {
        $date = 'YYYY'
    }

    if (is_month()) {
        $date = 'YYYY-mm'
    }

    if (is_day()) {
        $date = 'YYYY-mm-dd'
    }

    return $date
}
```

This works, but is this good practice, does this comply with OOP principles. How testable is this outside of Wordpress

Comment: outside wordpress: not, because your function is heavily dependant on the loop http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Comment: No, my code in not dependant on the loop, but on conditionals set by the main query which can be accessed **without** the loop

Comment: it still has no use outside of wordpress, unless the code your built around it works with static information for processing code